# Finding an Explicit Formula for $a_n$ from a Recurrence Relation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following recurrence relation

$$\beta ^n n(n+2)a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \beta^k (\alpha+k+1) a_k  , \quad  a_0=1, \quad n \ge 1 \tag{1}$$

where $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are positive real numbers.

I know that one can easily find $a_n$ by back substitution. Here is my question

> Is it possible to find an **explicit formula** for $a_n$?

---

**My Work**

I just computed the first three terms to see what I can guess. But I could not come up with anything!

$$\begin{align}
n&=1, \quad a_1=\beta^{-1} \left[ \frac{\alpha + 1}{1 \times 3} \right] \\
n&=2, \quad a_2=\beta^{-2}\left[ \frac{\alpha+1}{2 \times 4} + \frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}{(1 \times 3)(2 \times 4)} \right] \\
n&=3, \quad a_3=\beta^{-3}\left[ \frac{\alpha+1}{3 \times 5}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}{(1 \times 3)(3 \times 5)}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+3)}{(2 \times 4)(3 \times 5)}+\frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)(\alpha+3)}{(1 \times 3)(2 \times 4)(3 \times 5)} \right]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Since the sum ranges over $0 \le k \le n-1$, $n-k \ge 1$, and so the Kronecker delta function will always evaluate to $0$.  Can you not thus omit it from the formula?

Comment: @Shagnik: I think you are right! :) I didn't notice that! :) Can it be simplified further to get an explicit formula? :)

Comment: That I am not sure about. :)  I would try looking at the first few terms to see if you can spot a pattern, and then try using induction to prove its correctness.  This might be easier if you have a specific sequence $E_n$ in mind.

Comment: @Shagnik: Can you take a look at the question again, I made it a little simpler. :)

Comment: $$a_n = \frac{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2}\right)_n \left(
\frac{3-\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2}\right)_n}{\beta^n n! (3)_n}
\quad\iff\quad
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n = {}_2F_1\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2},\frac{3-\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2};3;\frac{z}{\beta}\right)
$$
where $(\beta)_n = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(\beta + k)$ is the
[Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) (aka, the rising factorial) and ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the comment of *Achille Hui*, I noticed that

$$\begin{align}
\beta ^n n(n+2)a_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \beta^k (\alpha+k+1) a_k \\
\beta ^{n-1} (n-1)(n+1)a_{n-1} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}  \beta^k (\alpha+k+1) a_k 
\end{align}$$

and subtracting the above equations will lead to

$$\begin{align}
\beta ^n n(n+2)a_n - \beta ^{n-1} (n-1)(n+1)a_{n-1} &= \beta^{n-1}(\alpha+n)a_{n-1} \\
\beta  n(n+2)a_n &= [n^2+n+(\alpha-1)] a_{n-1}
\end{align}$$
and finally

$$a_n=\frac{[n-(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2})][n-(\frac{-1-\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2})]}{\beta  n(n+2)}a_{n-1}$$

one can easily solve the above recurrence relation to get

$$a_n = \frac{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2}\right)_n \left( \frac{3-\sqrt{5-4\alpha}}{2}\right)_n}{\beta^n n! (3)_n}$$

where $(x)_n$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series).